# If a contact is deleted in Yahoo! mail, will it also delete the contact on the Android phone's contact list?

Tags: yahoo-mail

If a phone number is deleted off of Yahoo! mail, will the number also be deleted off of the Android device? If so, can the number reappear automatically or must it be reentered manually to reappear in yahoo mail contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
Any action taken in Yahoo! mail is not gonna effect the mobile contact.

Comment: What makes the contact reappear in yahoo mail contact list after it was deleted? I deleted a phone contact off of yahoo mail and it has reappeared, not once, but twice!